# Curve Fitting in a binary image, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, curve-fitting, binary-image

I have this Binary image `bw`:

[image]

edges  of an object  to carry out some measurements. But firstly I have to  do curve fitting  for both edges. The result should be two smooth curves representing edges.

I have the indices for each edge but I can not use them in making x-y data to be  input data to a fitting function. I mean they are not `x` and `f(x)`, actually, they all have the same value (1) with different positions. It is not right to say `[x y]=find(BW)` ; `y` here is not the value at `x`, but for sure there should be a way to use them to some kind of scale the binary image. I seem confused and I'm stuck here.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You want to get the `(x,y)` coordinates of each pixel belonging to a line, and then fit a function `[x;y]=f(t)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html)?

```
[y x] = find( bw );  %// get x y coordinates of all curve points
```

There are two small "tricks" you need to use here:

1. You have two curves, thus you need to split your data points to the left and right curves

   ```
   right = x<300;
   xr = x(right);
   yr = y(right);
   xl = x(~right);
   yl = y(~right);
   ```
2. Since your curves are close to vertical, it would be better to fit `x=f(y)` rather than the "classic" `y=f(x)`:

   ```
   pr = polyfit( yr, xr, 3 );  %// fit 3rd deg poly
   pl = polyfit( yl, xl, 3 );
   ```

Now you can plot them

```
yy = linspace( 1, size(bw,1), 50 );

figure; imshow(bw, 'border', 'tight' );
hold all
plot( polyval( pr, yy ), yy, '.-', 'LineWidth', 1 );
plot( polyval( pl, yy ), yy, '.-', 'LineWidth', 1 );
```

And you get:

[image]

If you want to create a new refined mask from the estimated curves, you can do the following:

```
yy = 1:size(bw,1);  %// single value per row
xxr=polyval(pr,yy); %// corresponding column values
xxl=polyval(pl,yy);
```

Set a new mask of the same size

```
nbw = false(size(bw)); 
nbw( sub2ind(size(bw),yy,round(xxr)) )=true;
nbw( sub2ind(size(bw), yy, round(xxl) )) = true;
```

And the result

```
figure;imshow(nbw,'border','tight');
```

[image]

Comment: It worked but just for plotting, I actually need to make the new curves indices "logical"(Ones) in the binary image itself ,not just a plot. I've tried but it seems I'm missing something, would you help me in this final step ?

Comment: @MohamedSayed you can get column value (X) for each row value (y), then round the X values to get indices

Comment: I appreciate your help, but to be honest, after my trials I still can't do it. And i think the points will be discrete or separate  in the binary image not smooth "continuous" curve !

Comment: @MohamedSayed the points in the binary image are, by definition, discrete. You cannot have pixels set in non integer locations

Comment: I know , I didn't mean that. I mean that I need to have a "logical one"  for each row .In other words,  there should be no gaps in the curve ...Anyways,  when I tried your suggestion, the same old edges came out  because for each row there're multiple column values not just one.